# ¿Como puedo dejar los mismos tamaños de diferentes gráficos en ggplot?

Tags: r, rstudio, ggplot2

Mi problema se presenta cuando corro los códigos, estos generan diferentes tamaños para cada gráfico.
Mi objetivo es dejar el mismo tamaño para cada gráfico en la "parte de colores" o eje x sin afectar los nombres del eje Y, con el fin de presentarlos.

Adjunto 2 imágenes diferentes:

[image: Imagen 1]

[image: Imagen 2]

Adjunto Código:

```
ggplot(grafico_obstaculo1, aes(obstaculo1,porcentaje_obstaculo,fill=areas_obstaculo))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", col='black')+
    #scale_y_continuous(labels = percent_format())+
    labs(title = "Obstáculos para la Innovación",
         x = "",
         y = "")+
    labs(fill = "")+
    coord_cartesian(ylim = percent(c(0, 1)*100))+
    #coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0,100))+
    # lo que sigue es para cambiar colores  
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("Alta"="#008CCF",
                               "Media"="#EF7918",
                               "Baja"="#009B72",
                               "Nula"="#943A8E"))+
    geom_text(aes(label=percent(porcentaje_obstaculo/100)),position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),vjust=1,size=4,color="black") + 
    geom_area()+
    geom_hline(yintercept = as.numeric(obstaculo_innovacion1[1,1]), color="red",size=0.7) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse=TRUE))+
    theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
    coord_flip()
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que las etiquetas del eje x en el segundo gráfico, son más largas que las del primero, por lo cual, se está "gastando" más espacio para poder mostrarlas. Un ejemplo:

```
library("ggplot2")

df <- data.frame(label=c('Etiqueta corta', 'Esta es una etiqueta bastante mas larga'), 
                 y=c(100, 500))

ggplot(df, aes(x=label, y=y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se puede hace en este caso, es agregar saltos de línea en alguno de los espacios de la etiqueta más larga y dividir de esta forma la etiqueta en múltiples líneas. Sin embargo resulta mucho más cómodo usar [`str_wrap()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stringr/versions/1.4.0/topics/str_wrap) del paquete `stringr`, ya que se puede aplicar a todas las etiquetas y establecer un ancho tentativo, usaremos `scale_x_discrete()` para configurar esto:

```
library("stringr")
ggplot(df, aes(x=label, y=y)) +
  geom_col() +
  coord_flip() + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) str_wrap(x, 10))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias Patricio.